# Is there a way to optimize this query? JOIN with several rows in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I need to make this query:

```
SELECT min(d.id) id, p.SERIAL serial, p.pos_id pos_id, MIN(fecha) fecha
FROM pvs p
JOIN devices d
ON d.SERIAL=p.SERIAL
GROUP BY p.SERIAL, p.pos_id
ORDER BY p.pos_id ASC;
```

The issue is that "pvs" is a very long table with plus 3 million rows. It's a table where I upload raw data but then I try to get the id of these elements in the working database (hence the min(d.id) part). that's also the reason why I didn't add a foreign key as such on pos_id in pvs.

The structure is the following:

```
CREATE TABLE pvs (
    `id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `pos_id` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `estado` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
    `fecha` DATETIME NOT NULL,
    `serial` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
    `created_at` TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `updated_at` TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE devices (
    `id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `serial` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
    `rotulo` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
    `code` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
    `cost_center` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
    `guia_recepcion` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `guia_reversa` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `pep` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
    `modified_by` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
    `modified_on` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `fecha_recepcion` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `fecha_instalacion` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `fecha_reversa` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `status_id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `location_id` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
    `customer_id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `str_id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `model_id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `pos_id` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `user_id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `technician_id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `created_at` TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `updated_at` TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `serial_prev` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
    `reversa_prev` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT NULL
)
```

Should I make p.serial a foreign key even though it's a varchar? If I just use p.pos_id as join clause "ids" are the same. I grouped it with min() because I needed to add it to the select without adding it to the "group by". I need the same columns for the query.

EDIT:

[image: The explain select]

Comment: is `d.serial` unique ?

Comment: No, it's not. It can show up in several ids.

Comment: What about `p.serial` ? is it unique ?

Comment: No it's not. That table tracks the status of a device in a location and actually they repeat a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

be sure you have proper index

```
    create index  idx1 on pvs( SERIAL);
```

and

```
    create index  idx2 on devices ( SERIAL);
```

Comment: Then it's not the answer.

Comment: why can't be indexed ????   the indexes  can be unique or not unique and in this case  two not unique index  can  resolve the performace problem  ..

Comment: The index can be or uniqie or not unique  ... the unioque is just a constrain for an index ..as you can see  in mysql doc https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-index.html  unique is an option  ..

Comment: @scaisEdge my bad, I thought indexes had to be unique, thanks

Comment: I'm still creating the index. It's taking a lot of time.

Comment: 3  million of rows are a  lot of  rows .

Comment: are you sure that the table are free for use ? .. there is not lock  for insert or update .. somewhere   .?.  (anyway for this test you should create some copied  tables .. or create table like withe index  and populate  with an insert/select)

Comment: Yes. It's all real data but not in production or anything like that.

Comment: Ok  ..  that'better  .. whick kind of server da disk you have  ??

Comment: I'm doing this in a computer with Windows 10 and a HDD.